# How do I make search results include ONLY pages, no posts?

Tags: search, post-type

I'm trying to return only pages in search results.

This is working:

`/?s=term&post_type=post`

It returns only posts, no pages.

But the opposite is not working:

`/?s=term&post_type=page`

This is returning pages and posts.

How do I return only pages?

**Edit**

Forgot to mention, so I'm trying to allow the ability for the user to click two links at the top of the search results page.

```
<a href="/?s=term&post_type=post">Search Only Posts</a>
<a href="/?s=term&post_type=page">Search Only Pages</a>
```

So, I can't just globally set all search results to only be one or the other.

Comment: `pre_get_posts` is your friend!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enforce a post type per callback on `pre_get_posts`:

```
is_admin() || add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( \WP_Query $query ) {

    $post_type = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'post_type', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

    if ( $post_type && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', [ $post_type ] );
});
```

If that still includes other post types, you have a second callback registered on that hook. Try to find it; it might be a theme or plugin.

Answer (score -1):

In your search.php, find The Loop and insert this code just after it. You can recognize the Loop because it usually starts with:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
```

***Code to be inserted:***

```
if (is_search() && ($post->post_type=='post')) continue;
```

So, your code should be like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
<?php if (is_search() && ($post->post_type=='post')) continue; ?>
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: This is not an ideal solution because pagination is not effected by this, therefore you will be able to use pagination to get to blank pages...